# Null variable value

Tags: php, html

I'm still new with `php`.

This is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>
    Data buku alamat dengan class
    </title>
</head>
<?php
    class orang
    {
        public $nama="";
        public $jk="";
        public $tptLahir="";
        public $tglLahir="";
        function umur()
        {
            list($tgl,$bln,$thn) = explode('-',$tglLahir); 
            $lahir = mktime(0, 0, 0, (int)$bln, (int)$tgl, $thn);
            $t = time();
            $umur = ($lahir < 0) ? ( $t - $lahir ) : $t - $lahir; 
            $tahun = 60 * 60 * 24 * 365; 
            $tahunlahir = $umur / $tahun; 
            $umursekarang=floor($tahunlahir); 
            return $umursekarang;
        }
        function tampilkan()
        {
            echo "<hr>Nama : ".$this->nama;
            echo "<hr>Jenis Kelamin : ".$this->jk;
            echo "<hr>Tempat Lahir : ".$this->tptLahir;
            echo "<hr>Tanggal Lahir : ".$this->tglLahir;
            echo "<hr>Umur : ".$this->umur();
        }
    }
?>
<body>
    <h1>
        Script : Data buku alamat dengan class
    </h1>
    <?php

        $orang1= new orang();
        $orang1->nama="Jack";
        $orang1->jk="laki-laki";
        $orang1->tptLahir="Jakarta";
        $orang1->tglLahir="12-09-1988";
        $orang1->tampilkan();

    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

There's no error. **The problem is that, the result of `$this->umur()` was *15*, not *26*.**

It seem the value in `public $tglLahir` variable not processed by function `umur()`.

Can anyone tell me where did i did wrong and help how to solve it?

Comment: *"The answer? The answer to what?"* - The Hitchhikers guide to the Galaxy.

Comment: What result?  What is this code supposed to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$tglLahir` is a property of the class `orang`, so in `umur()`, instead of:

```
list($tgl,$bln,$thn) = explode('-',$tglLahir);
```

you need to reference it as a property (`$this->tglLahir` instead of `$tglLahir`), so:

```
list($tgl,$bln,$thn) = explode('-',$this->tglLahir);
```

Comment: Wow, thnx XD ow, god, how can i forgot about that XD thnx alot :)

Answer (score 2):

You don't call the variable from your class `$tglLahir`, see:

```
list($tgl,$bln,$thn) = explode('-',$tglLahir);
```

So just change this line to this:

```
list($tgl,$bln,$thn) = explode('-',$this->tglLahir);
```

---

You almost spotted the error yourself (`It seem the value in public $tglLahir variable not processed by function umur()`)! I would recommend you to add error reporting while you are in testing environment, so you may can spot the next error yourself.

```
<?php
    ini_set("display_errors", 1);
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
?>
```

Comment: Wow, thnx XD ow, god, how can i forgot about that XD thnx alot :) i wish i can checklist both of you :)